# boolean Interface method unable to get the value from its implementation method

Tags: java

```
public interface Math{

public boolean result() throws exception;

}
```

//this is interface class

EJB class will implement this method

```
public class xyz implements Math{

public boolean result() throws exception;

boolean result = true;

return reult1;


}
```

Comment: Please explain better the problem and what you've tried.

Comment: Nothing works in your code. You should have a little more careful with the code that you post here.

Answer (score 2):

When you provide an implementation for a method, you must provide method's body in curly braces after the declaration, like this:

```
public class xyz implements Math{

    public boolean result() throws Exception {

        boolean result = true;

        return result;
    }

}
```

Note that since Java is case-sensitive, you need to properly capitalize the names of the classes, including the ones for the exceptions, i.e. you should write `throws Exception` instead of `throws exception` in both the interface and the class.

In addition, Java naming conventions suggest naming your classes starting in a capital letter. Consider renaming `xyz` to `Xyz`.

Comment: If you can help it, I'd also recommend not naming a class or interface `Math` since there is already an important predefined class with that name.

Comment: Yes, that would be in Curly Braces. Now i wanted to print that result but it doesn't allow me to print the result out.

Comment: @user2916626 Get your program to a state where it compiles by fixing this error. Do not add any new functionality yet. Once you are satisfied that the solution works, evaluate the functionality that you are about to add. If the change is small and similar to what you've described already, edit your question with what you have now. If the change is large, or is not similar to what you posted, accept this question by clicking the grey check mark, and start a new question describing the new problem.